# How to update property value, which has dynamically set property name?

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to update property value, which has dynamically set property name, but I can't figure out how to do it.

So I have an object like this, which has dynamically set property name (not value, the 'asd' - property name).

```
{period: "2020", asd: "5"}
```

Object is created like this:

```
let myTestObject = {
  period: "2020",
  [name]: "5"
};
```

Now when I want to update this object, I would assume it works like this, but it doesn't:

```
myTestObject.[name] = "new value"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). (It's either a dot or brackets, not both. `myTestObject[name] = "new value"` or `myTestObject.asd = "new value"`) see: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Yes, thanks. The issue was somewhere else why it wasn't updating though, but at least I now know the right way.